# jQuery - Wait for looped DistanceMatrixService to return final callback before continuing

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of addresses in json that I'd like to iterate over and lookup the distance from a single lon/lat (html5 geolocation). I'm looking to find the address (json item) with the shortest distance and do something with it later.

I'm using [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) library and jquery 1.10

1. I set the user's location data in a cookie. (is there a better way?)
2. Then I iterate through the json addresses and get closest address to
   this cookie (via the loop), then set another cookie with that data. (is there a
   better way?)
3. At this point, I'd like to display the closest address as html to the user based on the cookie set.

The problem with my setup is that the DistanceMatrixService callback is async and returning *after* the function that's responsible for displaying the closest address to the user.

The code looks like this:

**HTML5 Geolocation Code:**

```
function get_user_location() {
  window.onload = function () {
    var html5Options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 6000, maximumAge: 0 };
    geolocator.locate(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError, true, html5Options);
  };

  function onGeoSuccess(location) {
    $.cookie('user_postal_code', location.address.postalCode);
    $.cookie('user_latitude', location.coords.latitude);
    $.cookie('user_longitude', location.coords.longitude);
    get_hca_rss();
  }

  function onGeoError(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

get_user_location();
```

**jSON pull:**

```
function get_hca_rss() {
  var hcafeed = 'http://hcafeeds.medcity.net/rss/er/rss_feed.xml';
  var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from rss where url="' + hcafeed + '"') + '&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(yql,function(data){
    if(data) {
      get_closest_er(data);
    }
  });
}
```

**Get the closest address:**

```
function get_closest_er(data, userLocation) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var rows = data.query.results.item;
  var origin = $.cookie('user_latitude') + "," + $.cookie('user_longitude');

  $.each(rows,function(e) {
    if(rows[e].address != undefined) {
      var destination = rows[e].address;
      tmp = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
      closestIndex = null;

      // Google Distance Matrix API
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      service.getDistanceMatrix( {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        durationInTraffic: false,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false,
      }, callback);

      // Callback for distance api
      function callback(response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
          alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } else {
          var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
          if (distance < tmp) {
            tmp = distance;
            $.cookie('closestIndex',e);
            $.cookie('closestDistance',response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
          }
        }
      }

    }
  });

  set_closest_er_html(data);

};
```

**Set that HTML:**

```
function set_closest_er_html(data) {
  var rows = data.query.results.item;
  var hElem = $('#closestER');
  var uZip = $.cookie('user_postal_code');
  var cIdx = $.cookie('closestIndex');
  var cHospital = rows[cIdx];
  var cName = cHospital.comments.replace(" ER Wait Time", "");
  var cDistance = $.cookie('closestDistance').replace(" mi", "");
  var cWaitTime = cHospital.description.replace(" Mins", "");

  hElem.html('<h2>Hospital Info:</h2>');
  hElem.append('<div><span>Your Closest ER </span><span>' + uZip + ' Zip Code</span></div>');
  hElem.append('<div><strong>Hospital </strong><span>' + cName + '</span></div>');
  hElem.append('<div><label>Distance: </label><div>' + cDistance + '</div> Miles</div>');
  hElem.append('<div><label>Wait: </label><div>' + cWaitTime + '</div> Minutes</div>');
}
```

I guess the question is... how do I wait until the last callback() function in the loop is complete and the closest address cookies are set before it moves on to the set_closest_er_html function?

Thanks in advance.